# Source filtering an array of objects in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is a document in ElasticSearch

```
"CompanyId": 5733,
"PartNumber": "W8S038",
"Name_en": "#8 Washer, M4 Compatible, Stainless Steel, Pack of 100",
"ProductId": 90023,
"CompanyName": "Washers Ltd",
"Prices": [

    {
        "BuyerId": 308,
        "Price": 2.42
    }
    ,
    {
        "BuyerId": 406,
        "Price": 2.22
    }
]
}
```

Obviously we can't let on to buyer 308 that buyer 406 is getting a better price. Therefore when buyer 308 is searching I need to remove all of the prices for *other* buyers.

I'd like to do this by using source filtering. But how?!

(I could exclude `Prices` and add back in the required price by using a `script_field`. However, that means that the price is not part of the source document and therefore ReactiveSearch can't see it and therefore can't sort on it.)

Update: here is the query generated by ReactiveSearch to which I need to append the limit on prices:

```
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must":[
                     {
                        "bool":{
                           "must":[
                              {
                                 "bool":{
                                    "should":[
                                       {
                                          "multi_match":{
                                             "query":"m4 washer",
                                             "fields":[
                                                "Name_en"
                                             ],
                                             "type":"cross_fields",
                                             "operator":"and"
                                          }
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "multi_match":{
                                             "query":"m4 washer",
                                             "fields":[
                                                "Name_en"
                                             ],
                                             "type":"phrase_prefix",
                                             "operator":"and"
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ],
                                    "minimum_should_match":"1"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
"filter": [            
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Prices",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "Prices.CompanyId": 1474
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]      
      }
   },
   "size":10,
   "aggs":{
      "CompanyName.raw":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"CompanyName.raw",
            "size":1000,
            "order":{
               "_count":"desc"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "_source":{
      "excludes":[
         "PurchasingViews",
         "ContractFilters",
         "SearchField*",
         "Keywords*",
         "Menus*"
      ]
   },
   "from":0,
   "sort":[
      {
         "Name_en.raw":{
            "order":"asc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "script_fields":{
      "price":{
         "script":{
            "lang":"painless",
            "inline":"if(params['_source']['Prices'] != null){for(p in params['_source']['Prices']){ if(p.CompanyId == 1474) return p.Price; }} return null;"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

(That `bool, must, bool, must, bool, must, bool, should` seems rather stupid?)

Comment: How are you filtering price, using max aggregation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) feature like below.

```
{
  "_source": [
    "CompanyId", "PartNumber", "Name_en", "ProductId", "CompanyName"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [            
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Prices",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "Prices.BuyerId": 308
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the output you'll get exactly what you expect, namely all the root-level fields and the matching prices for the given buyer.

**UPDATE**:

Here is how I would rewrite your query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": "1",
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "m4 washer",
            "fields": [
              "Name_en"
            ],
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "m4 washer",
            "fields": [
              "Name_en"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Prices",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "Prices.CompanyId": 1474
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "CompanyName.raw": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CompanyName.raw",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "PurchasingViews",
      "ContractFilters",
      "SearchField*",
      "Keywords*",
      "Menus*",
      "Prices"
    ]
  },
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "Name_en.raw": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "price": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "if(params['_source']['Prices'] != null){for(p in params['_source']['Prices']){ if(p.CompanyId == 1474) return p.Price; }} return null;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That works! Cool; thank you.

Now, how do I append that to an existing query?

Comment: Great! Update your question with the query you have.

Comment: As far as I can tell if you take all the `bool, must` out and leave just `bool, should` then you get the same result. However, wherevever I put the `filter` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh, hang on, it's producing an `inner_hits` property in the results; not removing the unwanted prices from the document.

Comment: In the inner_hits section you only get the prices for CompanyId 1474. See my updated answer